# UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height: Invalid constraints in tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to find the cleanest way to adjust the height of my UITableView's tableHeaderView, which is itself just a view with a multiline label. It seems like autolayout should be able to figure out the height pretty easily.

I create the label like so:

```
DDInsetLabelView *header = [[DDInsetLabelView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
header.insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.f, 10.f, 10.f, 10.f);
header.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", self.categoryTitle, self.subcategoryTitle];
header.label.numberOfLines = 0;
header.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
```

within the label class, I handle layout like so:

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];

    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"t": @(self.insets.top), @"l": @(self.insets.left),
                              @"b": @(self.insets.bottom), @"r": @(self.insets.right)};
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_label);
    self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(t)-[_label]-(b)-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(l)-[_label]-(r)-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.label.frame.size.width;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Now, here is how I am calculating the height for the header view in my controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    UIView *header = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    NSLayoutConstraint *headerWidthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:header attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:header.frame.size.width];
    [header addConstraint:headerWidthConstraint];
    CGFloat height = [header systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    [header removeConstraint:headerWidthConstraint];

    header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, header.frame.size.width, height);
    header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
}
```

It appears as tho this works fine visually, but I keep getting the following error in the console:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2e5bb7540 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[DDInsetLabelView:0x7fb2e5b53250(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2e5bb84b0 V:|-(10)-[UILabel:0x7fb2e5b65200'Custom Box\nCustomize with...']   (Names: '|':DDInsetLabelView:0x7fb2e5b53250 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb2e5bb8500 V:[UILabel:0x7fb2e5b65200'Custom Box\nCustomize with...']-(10)-|   (Names: '|':DDInsetLabelView:0x7fb2e5b53250 )>"
)
```

I am assuming that the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` represents some internally calculated height value for the header. How can I avoid this warning while using autolayout to calculate the height of my header??

Comment: Have this same issue, but with a more simple approach. Using Xcode 6.3.2, I'm able to just assign my auto-layout, xib-based view to the `tableHeaderView` property. Height and width just work. However, when I segue to another view, then return, I get that same NSLayoutConstraint warning, and the `tableHeaderView` changes height for no reason... especially to 0. :(

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the line ... `header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;`

Also, add `[header setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]` when creating your header